# How to rotate a polygon around it's center?

Tags: java, rotation

I've found other questions asking how to do this but I haven't gotten any of them to work. I'm trying to write a method that rotates a polygon around it's center a number of degrees. My current code makes it disappear from the screen when it moves a degree.

```
    public void rotate(double angle) {
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

    int xCoords [] = {(int)line1.getX1(), (int)line2.getX1(), (int)line3.getX1()};
    int yCoords [] = {(int)line1.getY1(), (int)line2.getY1(), (int)line3.getY1()};

    Polygon polygon = new Polygon(xCoords, yCoords, 3);

    at.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), getX(), getY());

    for (int i = 0; i < polygon.npoints; i++){
        Point p = new Point(polygon.xpoints[i], polygon.ypoints[i]);
        at.transform(p, p);
        //System.out.println(p.x);
        //System.out.println(p.y);
        poly.addPoint(p.x, p.y);
    }

    setA(poly.xpoints[1], poly.ypoints[1]);
    setB(poly.xpoints[2], poly.ypoints[2]);
    setC(poly.xpoints[3], poly.ypoints[3]);
}
```

edit: include attempt

Comment: Please include one of your attempts and describe where you're stuck.

Comment: You use `polygon` in some statements and `poly` in others. Is that intentional? Have you tried printing trace for the points after the transform? If so, what results did you get? Are you certain the centre of the polygon around which it rotates is set correctly?

Comment: yes. I'm not sure what you mean, and not quite but if I set it to its known center and try to rotate it I still have the same issue.